# El proceso no puede obtener acceso al archivo porque está siendo utilizado en otro proceso. C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Cuando imprimo un documento, y trato de eliminarlo despues, me sale el siguiente error:

**El proceso no puede obtener acceso al archivo C:\T33F9472.pdf porque está siendo utilizado en otro proceso.**

El codigo que uso es el siguiente:

```
String pathTmp = "C:\\" + "T33F9472.pdf"+ ".pdf";
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pathTmp, FileMode.Create))
        {
            fs.Write(renderedBytes, 0, renderedBytes.Length);
            fs.Close();
            SendToPrinter(pathTmp);
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(pathTmp))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(pathTmp);
            }
            file_name = fileContentResult.FileDownloadName;
        }

 private void SendToPrinter(String filePath)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.Verb = "print";
        info.FileName = filePath;
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        using (Process p = new Process())
        {
            p.StartInfo = info;
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForInputIdle();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }
        //if (p.CloseMainWindow()==false) Esta linea esta comentada, porque me salia error, no me servia.
        //    p.Kill(); 

    }
```

Además, me gustaría saber si el ProcessStartInfo puede leer archivo binario, en vez de ruta de un archivo fisico.
Como podría solucionar este problema.Desde ya, gracias.

Comment: por algo en particular estas lanzando un proceso para mandar algo a imprimir?

Comment: Si, estoy mandando a imprimir un documento que guardo y después lo elimino. Hubiera sido ideal, enviar el documento en binario (byte[]) para imprimir, para no crear uno físico y después tener que eliminarlo.

Answer (score 3):

Creo que tú problema radica en que estas tratando de eliminar el archivo estando aún dentro del `using` que lo está creando, intenta lo siguiente:

```
String pathTmp = "C:\\" + "T33F9472.pdf"+ ".pdf";
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pathTmp, FileMode.Create))
{
   fs.Write(renderedBytes, 0, renderedBytes.Length);
   fs.Close();
   SendToPrinter(pathTmp);   
   file_name = fileContentResult.FileDownloadName;
}

if (System.IO.File.Exists(pathTmp))
{
   System.IO.File.Delete(pathTmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución no es en C# sino en Visual Basic con Visual Studio. "Está siendo utilizado por  otro proceso". Hay unos comandos muy repetitivos y con el mismo nombre: "Salir"/BtnSalir de cada Form. He cambiado este BtnSalir para todos con BtnSalirInformes, BtnSalirRelacion, BtnSalirPersonal, o lo que sea, pero distintos. Me ha desaparecido el problema. Feliz Año Nuevo.

Answer (score -2):

el problema se me soluciono utilizando el código siguiente

```
try

       { tu codigo }


   Exit Function

Catch ex As Exception

         MsgBox(ex.Message & "...problemas CON GENERAR SELLO DIGITAL ")
End Try
```

Comment: Esto solo captura un error y muestra un mensaje, ¿como puede solucionar cuando el archivo esta siendo utilizado por un proceso.?